# how to give a version to mdb files

Tags: c++, ms-access, mfc

I am using a .mdb file as a database for a dialog based application. For the each  Release I want to give a version to the mdb file if there are more entries added. using C++ i want to read the version and display it in the application.

Can you please tell me if it is possible to give a version to mdb file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a table to MDB and track releases there. If MDB should change release number automatically after some data changes, you can use Data Macro (this is for Access 2010+)

Comment: thanks for the reply. i am using Access 2002-2003 file format, can u plz suggest any solution for identifying the version without having to open the database ? (cause opening the database is bit time consuming)

Comment: MDB opening is quite fast, but if you don't want to open it, keep version information somewhere else, for instance in text file next to mdb. It will be not really good solution though.

Comment: How would you add a version to a text file without opening that text file? How do you add a version to a word file without opening it? How do you add a version to any plane jane windows file? You talking about a file sitting on a disk drive. I see nothing here that would pertain JUST to  mdb file, or a simple XML file. Unless you place some version information inside the  file and then open + read that information, there really not a lot you can do. The only suggestion would be to place the version number as part of the file name if you are looking to avoid opening the file in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom property:

```
db.CreateProperty("VersionId", dbText, "1.0.0")
```

then add this to the database, but there is no way to read this without opening the database file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do that and its probably best to do it as a db.property like @Gustav proposed.

If for some reason it is important to have a version information that you can read without opening the file as access file there are still some options:

- There is the [Windows Shell Property System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that I think allows you to add Properties to every File/Folder.
- You could change the Creation Date for the file to fit your need.
- You could perhaps even read/change the file content itself in a binary stream if you research it thouroughly enough.
- and you can of course have an external .txt (or .ver or whatever) file that you update automatically from the db.property whenever you open the db.